# A particular Linked List C Function

Tags: c, list

I need to write a C function which works on a linked list like this:

```
struct list {
    int value;
    struct list * next_ptr;
}
```

This function takes as input a threshold number and the list itself, then it has to:

1) Add +1 to every integer in the list
2) Then check which one has become bigger than threshold and remove it
3) Give as output the number of deleted elements

The list must be ordered from smallest to biggest (eg: 1 2 3 4 YES, 4 3 2 1 or 1 3 2 4 NO...)

An example of how it should work:

- Values in the list: 2 4 6 8
- Threshold value: 6
- The list becomes 3 5 7 9
- The function removes 7 and 9 -> 3 5 are not removed
- The output is 2, because 2 values have been removed...

This is the code I've written, but actually it doesn't work, I think there are some issues with pointers:

FUNCTION:

```
int thres_erase(struct list ** ptrptr, int thres){
int count;
visit_incr(ptrptr);
while (*ptrptr != NULL){
    if ((*ptrptr)->value > thres){
        consume(ptrptr);
        count ++;
        ptrptr= &((*ptrptr)->next_ptr);
       }
    else
        ptrptr= &((*ptrptr)->next_ptr);
}
return count;
}
```

(Count is the number of deleted elements)

The other 2 functions used (They actually work fine):

```
void consume (struct list ** ptrptr){
struct list *tmp_ptr;
    if (*ptrptr != NULL){
        tmp_ptr = *ptrptr;
        *ptrptr = (*ptrptr)->next_ptr;
        free(tmp_ptr);
    }
    else
        printf("\nEmpty!");

void visit_incr( struct list ** ptr ) {
    while ( *ptr != NULL ) {
          (*ptr)->value = (*ptr)->value + 1;
          ptr = &((*ptr)->next_ptr);
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a solution which do not drastically change the function, just make it work...

Comment: Can you describe in what way the current code does not work?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see is when you call "visit_incr", it updates ptrptr to the end of the list, so your while loop never runs.

```
visit_incr(ptrptr);
    while (*ptrptr != NULL){
```

In general, you should learn to attach a debugger and step through your code or at the very least use printfs so you can actually see what your code is doing.  Otherwise coding will be extremely painful.

Comment: The debugger says "SIGSEGV" at the same line you talked about (the one with loop)

Comment: Awesome.  That means ptrptr == NULL when you call it, and you're dereferencing it.  Not surprising, because as I said in my answer, visit_incr has incremented it to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing your ptrptr twice! First in

```
consume(), *ptrptr = (*ptrptr)->next_ptr;
```

and again in

```
thres_erase(), ptrptr= &((*ptrptr)->next_ptr);
```

Choose one.

Edit

In consume() function you don't have to check

```
if (*ptrptr != NULL){...}
```

because ptrptr is already != NULL, in thres_erase()

```
while (*ptrptr != NULL){...}
```

Edit: the code

In your main()

```
//Your code...
struct list *temp_ptr = NULL;
temp_ptr = head_ptr; //head_ptr points to the first node
visit_incr(&temp_ptr);

if(head_ptr != NULL){
    temp_ptr = head_ptr;

    count = thres_erase(&temp_ptr, thres); //For all nodes except the first one

    temp_ptr = head_ptr;
    if(temp_ptr->value > thres){temp_ptr = temp_ptr->next_ptr; free(head_ptr); count++;}
    head_ptr = temp_ptr;
}
else{printf("No nodes in the list \n");}

//print your list
temp_ptr = head_ptr;

while(temp_ptr != NULL){
    printf("%d ", temp_ptr->value);

    temp_ptr = temp_ptr->next_ptr;
}
//Your code...
```

change thres_erase(), consume().

```
int thres_erase(struct list **ptrptr, int thres){
    int count;
    struct list *temp;
    temp = *ptrptr;

    while(temp->next_ptr != NULL){
        if( (temp->next_ptr)->value > thres){
            count++;
            consume( &temp );
        }
        else{
            temp = temp->next_ptr;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

void consume (struct list ** ptrptr){
    struct list *tmp_ptr;

    tmp_ptr = (*ptrptr)->next_ptr;
    (*ptrptr)->next_ptr = ((*ptrptr)->next_ptr)->next_ptr;
    free(tmp_ptr);

    return;
}
```

valter

Comment: Then how should i fix this?